# How can I go about adding a pause and go button and some sliders to my fluid simulation to update it in real time without resetting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, dynamic, interactive

I have some code that creates a fluid simulation and I changed it so that it keeps running and advancing the system indefinitely until the user closes the window. Next, I would like to add a pause and go button and a few sliders for changing certain parameters (ie viscosity, inflow velocity, etc.) to make it more interactive. Every time the user moves one of the sliders, I want the animation to continue running but with the new parameters rather than starting all over again. I have not been able to find any resources that answer this question for updating live animations. How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Here is my code to show you what I have now. I'm trying to do this in pure matplotlib. This code does work but just doesn't have the sliders and buttons added yet

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from fluid import Fluid

RESOLUTION = 85, 160
VISCOSITY = 1e-5
INFLOW_RADIUS = RESOLUTION[0]*0.12
INFLOW_VELOCITY = RESOLUTION[1]*0.14

directions = (np.array([-0.2960987711,0.9551573264]), np.array([0,0]), np.array([0.2960987711,-0.9551573264]))
points = (np.array([RESOLUTION[0]*(0.225), 0]), np.array([-100, 0]), np.array([RESOLUTION[0]*(0.775), RESOLUTION[1]]))

channels = 'r', 'g', 'b'
fluid = Fluid(RESOLUTION, VISCOSITY, channels)


inflow_dye_field = np.zeros((fluid.size, len(channels))) # creating the array to be iterated over. This is the environment that the fluid will exist in
inflow_velocity_field = np.zeros_like(fluid.velocity_field) # creating the array for representing the initial velocity field which will tell the fluid how it needs to advance through successive iterations

def setup_flow():
    for i, p in enumerate(points):
        distance = np.linalg.norm(fluid.indices - p, axis=1)
        mask = distance <= INFLOW_RADIUS

        for d in range(2):
            inflow_velocity_field[..., d][mask] = directions[i][d] * INFLOW_VELOCITY

        inflow_dye_field[..., i][mask] = 1

setup_flow()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Fluid Simulation')

def animate(args):
   
    fluid.advect_diffuse()

    fluid.velocity_field += inflow_velocity_field

    for i, k in enumerate(channels):
        fluid.quantities[k] += inflow_dye_field[..., i]

    fluid.project()

    rgb = np.dstack(tuple(fluid.quantities[c] for c in channels))

    rgb = rgb.reshape((*RESOLUTION, 3))
    rgb = (np.clip(rgb, 0, 1) * 255).astype('uint8')
    
    im.set_data(rgb)

rgb = np.dstack(tuple(fluid.quantities[c] for c in channels))

rgb = rgb.reshape((*RESOLUTION, 3))
rgb = (np.clip(rgb, 0, 1) * 255).astype('uint8')

ax.xaxis.set_visible(False); ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
im = ax.imshow(rgb, animated=True)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=30)
plt.show()
```

Edit: I have tried using Tkinter to do this and while it's not too difficult to embed a matplotlib animation in a Tkinter window, the buttons and sliders in Tkinter don't work for the embedded plot. Also, changing the rest of my code so that it's in pure Tkinter will work but it will be an absolute nightmare and I am not confident enough with that library yet to be able to do that given the amount of time I have.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with pure matplotlib but you can easily embed a plot in a tkinter application `from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg`, and add any button you need there.

Comment: You can also look into [widgets](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/buttons.html): I've never used them, but it looks like you could change the global sim parameters in the callbacks without stopping the animation (but note that many of the params you want to change are used in the setup, so that might be tricky, I don't know how the simulation code is organized). Also side note, when you edit the post the commenters do not receive a notification (I only saw that because I had the tab still open by chance :) ) it's better to leave a comment to notify them.

Comment: Thank you @Pietro . Your advice is helpful and you make a very good observation about the issue of the parameters I want to change being in the set up. I will look more into the widgets as you mentioned and will comment to reply to comments on my posts in future! :)